# String containing time (1H4M10S) converted to seconds

Tags: java, time

I want to convert a string that looks like this "5W3D10H5M10S" to seconds, the function would return "3319510", when having the previous string as an argument.

- W = Week(s)
- D = Day(s)
- H = Hour(s)
- M = Minute(s)
- S = Second(s)

I've been thinking of ways to do this, but none of them will be efficient, if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: You could split the string and make a calculation per unit:
5w = 5*7*24*3600 seconds and so on

Comment: Not going to get a lot more efficient than splitting up the string and doing the multiplication. No shortcut to be had, you just have to write the code.

Comment: I was thinking there might be a function like this which is already implemented in java or a small class for it.

Comment: Interestingly I tried to do this one with `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("w'W'D'D'K'H'm'M's'S'"); Date myDate = sdf.parse` as he was looking for a prebuilt Java function but it didn't work. I wonder why... (I put it in the try/catch block but it just gave a really wrong number. weird).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about translate your string into an expression and let `ScriptEngineManager` do the calculation?

```
public void testIt() throws Exception {
        final String in = "5W3D10H5M10S";
        final String after = in.replaceAll("W", "*7D").
                replaceAll("D", "*24H").
                replaceAll("H", "*60M").
                replaceAll("M", "*60+").
                replaceAll("S", "");
        final ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        final ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        final Object result = engine.eval(after);
        System.out.println("Result:" + String.valueOf(result));
    }
```

output:

```
Result:3319510.0
```

Comment: This fits me perfectly, because it doesn't matter which order you enter the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can parse it back with the help of a regular expression, see below an implementation with Java 7 :

```
    String str = "5W3D10H5M10S";
    String pat = "((?<week>\\d+)W)?((?<day>\\d+)D)?((?<hour>\\d+)H)?((?<min>\\d+)M)?((?<sec>\\d+)S)?";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile (pat).matcher(str);

    if(m.matches()) {
        int week = Integer.parseInt( m.group("week") );
        int day  = Integer.parseInt( m.group("day") );
                    //And so on ..
    }
```

Comment: I would additionally suggest building the regex itself in a loop, with `String.format`, I think it would be actually easier to comprehend that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a regexp and a simple loop:

```
private static final int[] timeMul = new int[] {7, 24, 60, 60, 1};
private static final Pattern rx = Pattern.compile(
    "(?:(\\d+)W)?(?:(\\d+)D)?(?:(\\d+)H)?(?:(\\d+)M)?(?:(\\d+)S)?"
);
public static int getSeconds(String str) {
    Matcher m = rx.matcher(str);
    if (!m.find()) {
        return -1;
    }
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != m.groupCount() ; i++) {
        String g = m.group(i+1);
        res += g == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(g);
        res *= timeMul[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Link to ideone.](http://ideone.com/yEw91S)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to simple loop through the text until it reaches a non numerical character then take a substring of the previous character location and get that section of text, parse it to int and multiply it by the amount needed according to the character.

Example:

```
public long getSeconds(String funnyFormat) 
{
    long seconds = 0;
    int lastIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<funnyFormat.length;i++) {
        char cur = funnyFormat.charAt(i);
        if(cur < '0' && cur > '9') {
            //If it's not a Number
            int seg = Integer.parseInt(funnyFormat.substring(lastIndex,i));
            lastIndex = i+1;
            switch(cur){
            case 'H':
                long += seg*3600;
                break;
            case 'M':
                long += seg*60;
                break;
            case 'S':
                long += seg;
                break;
            //And so on and so forth
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to tweak this to take care of some boundary conditions and unexpected input...

```
long wdh(String fmt) {

    long tot = 0;
    int current = 0;
    for (char c : fmt.toCharArray()) {

        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            current *= 10;
            current += c - '0';
            continue;
        }

        switch (c) {

            case 'W': tot += WEEK_SECONDS * current; current = 0; continue;
            case 'D': tot += DAY_SECONDS * current; current = 0; continue;
            case 'H': tot += HOUR_SECONDS * current; current = 0; continue;
            case 'M': tot += MINUTE_SECONDS * current; current = 0; continue;
            case 'S': tot += current; break;
        }
    }

    return tot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Little simplified(Less string manipulations)**

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d'D'HH'H'mm'M'ss'S'");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String dateString = "5W3D10H5M10S";
    String[] dateAndWeek = dateString.split("W");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(dateAndWeek[1]));
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dateAndWeek[0]));
    long dateSeconds = cal.getTimeInMillis()/1000;//<--3319510
```

Comment: @BlackVoid: I got this pattern working with Calendar function. If you are looking for this kind of approach, I am sure, I can simplify it better.